# passing up headers from auth_request

Tags: nginx

I have an authorization module which is called whenever a request is made to a private endpoint.

The module parses the token from the `Authorization` header, and:

1. if it's invalid, it returns 401
2. if it's valid, it returns 200
3. if it's valid but is about to expire in X minutes, it generates a new token and returns that one in the `Authorization` header.

"profile" is one of the private endpoints, and it's configured this way:

```
location /profile {
  auth_request /jwtverify;

  auth_request_set  $authorization $upstream_http_authorization;
  proxy_set_header  authorization $authorization;
  proxy_pass        http://private-profile:80;
}
```

`jwtverify` is configured this way:

```
location = /jwtverify {
  internal;
  proxy_pass              http://auth-module:8080/auth/verify;
  proxy_pass_request_body off;
  proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
  proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
  auth_request_set        $http_authorization $upstream_http_authorization;
}
```

Now, everything works except for requirement no. 3: if the auth module sets the `Authorization` header, the client never receives it.

The flow should be like this:

- Client makes the request
- `auth-module` intercepts the request and, if valid, the proxy passes it to the private service
- When the response is sent, headers set by `auth-module` should be kept and sent to the client

I think I didn't understand properly how to combine `auth_request_set`, `proxy_set_header`, `auth_request_set`, it might also be that they aren't correct for this scenario.

Is there a way to accomplish this in NGINX?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I was able to do that with the help of the [`headers_more`](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module) module.

The full configuration is:

```
location = /jwtverify {
  internal;
  proxy_pass              http://auth-module:8080/auth/verify;
  proxy_pass_request_body off;
  proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
  proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}

location /profile {
  auth_request /jwtverify;

  # this gets called right after auth_request returns.
  # it reads http "authorization" header from upstream (= auth_request)
  # and sets it to the variable $auth_header
  # https://stackoverflow.com/a/31485557/1759845
  auth_request_set $auth_header $upstream_http_authorization;

  # this gets called right before sending response to client.
  # it adds the previously set variable (= "authorization" 
  # header from auth_request) to the response
  more_set_headers "Authorization: $auth_header";

  proxy_pass        http://private-profile:80;
}
```

Comment: Was the blockage simply that you're trying to use the standard `Authorization` header to return the new token? If you used a private header, could this use `add_header` instead of `more_set_headers`?

Comment: @TBBle I honestly don't know. It would be a limitation though, as this specific header needs to be the standard `Authorization` header, so even if that was the issue I'd still be using `more_set_headers`

Comment: Thank you. I ask because I have a similar use-case, but am free to use a custom header for the return channel, while not being as-free to add non-standard modules to the system (in this case to the Kubernetes NGINX Ingress distribution). For anyone else in my situation, I found [a bug report on that distribution](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3716) that indicates it would work for `add_header` but other functionality such as `if` would not function correctly due to the operation of `proxy_pass`.

Answer (score 8):

This is how I was able to solve this without a custom module:

```
location /auth {
  internal;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/auth;
  proxy_pass_request_body off;
  proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
  proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
  proxy_set_header X-Original-Remote-Addr $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Original-Host $host;
}

location /protected {
  auth_request /auth;
  auth_request_set $authentication_id $sent_http_x_authentication_id;
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/protected;
  proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
  proxy_set_header X-Original-Remote-Addr $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Original-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Authentication-Id: $authentication_id;
}
```

1. Have your `/auth` endpoint include a response header. Mine sets `X-Authentication-Id`
2. Use `auth_request_set` to set a variable based on the response header
3. Use the variable to set the header as part of the `/protected` request

Comment: This is the better answer IMHO.

Comment: Does this only add the header if the `auth_request` subrequest responds positively (200)? If you get a 403 then the header is not added, right?

Comment: your `/auth` endpoint is in control of that. If you don't want it, don't add it before you return a response.